# Solve differential equation by a variable change.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is the problem I am facing:

Find the general solution to $(1-t^2)^2 x'' - t x' + a^2 x = 0$

Hint: Use a change of variable $t = \phi(u)$ such that after the change of variable there is no coefficient in x' and then use techniques to reduce the order of the equation.

This is my progress:

I am starting with differential equations so I will write $dx/dt$ instead of just $x'$ in order to not get confused between differentiating against $t$ or $u$ (sorry if the english grammar is not correct). Thus, I'll rewrite my equation as

$(1-t^2)^2 \dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2} - t \dfrac{dx}{dt} + a^2x = 0$

Then I apply then change of variable $t = \phi(u)$. Let's put $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$ and $ \dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2} $ in terms of  $\dfrac{dx}{du}$ by using the chain rule (I will omit the argument of $\phi$ (which is always $u$ so that the equations don't get messy):

$\dfrac{dx}{du}$ = $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$ $\dfrac{dt}{du}$ = $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$ $\phi' \Longrightarrow \dfrac{dx}{dt} = \dfrac{dx}{du} \dfrac{1}{\phi'}$

$\dfrac{d^2x}{du^2} =  \dfrac{d}{du}\left( \dfrac{dx}{du}\right) =  \dfrac{d}{du}\left( \dfrac{dx}{dt}  \dfrac{dt}{du}\right) =  \dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2} \dfrac{dx}{du} \dfrac{dx}{du} + \dfrac{dx}{dt} \dfrac{d^2t}{du^2} =  \dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2} \phi'^2 + \dfrac{dx}{dt} \phi'' $

From the last line we can obtain $d^2x/dt^2$:

$\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2} = \dfrac{1}{\phi'^2}(\dfrac{d^2x}{du^2} - \phi'' \dfrac{dx}{dt})
= \dfrac{1}{\phi'^2}\left(\dfrac{d^2x}{du^2} - \dfrac{\phi''}{\phi'} \dfrac{dx}{du}\right)$

Now we can rewrite the original equation as:

$(1-\phi(u)^2)^2\left(\frac{1}{\phi'^2}\left(\dfrac{d^2x}{du^2} - \dfrac{\phi''}{\phi'} \dfrac{dx}{du}\right)\right) - \phi(u) \left(\dfrac{dx}{du} \dfrac{1}{\phi'}\right) + a^2 x = 0$

Sorting and using $x'$ and $x''$ again:

$\dfrac{(1-\phi(u)^2)^2}{(\phi(u)')^2} x'' +\left(\dfrac{(1-\phi(u)^2)^2 \phi''(u)}{(\phi'(u))^3} + \dfrac{\phi(u)}{\phi'(u)}\right) x'+ a^2 x = 0$

Now following the hint:

$\dfrac{(1-\phi(u)^2)^2 \phi''(u)}{(\phi'(u))^3} + \dfrac{\phi(u)}{\phi'(u)} = 0
\Longrightarrow (1-\phi^2)^2 \phi'' + \phi (\phi')^2 = 0
$

I cannot solve that for $\phi$

:S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve  :
$$\tag{1}\left(1-\phi^2\right)^2\,\phi'' + \phi\;(\phi')^2 = 0$$

You may set $\;v(\phi):=(\phi')^2\,$ to get :
$$\frac d{du}v(\phi)=2\,\phi'\phi''=\frac {dv(\phi)}{d\phi}\frac {d\phi}{du}$$
so that $\;v'_{\phi}=2\,\phi''$ and $(1)$ becomes a linear ODE :

$$(1-\phi^2)^2\,v'_{\phi} + 2\phi\;v = 0$$

$$\frac{dv}v=- \;\frac{2\;\phi\;d\phi}{(1-\phi^2)^2}$$
with the general solution :
$$v(\phi)=(\phi')^2=C_1\;e^{\frac 1{\phi^2-1}}$$
giving :
$$\tag{2}\phi(u)'=C\;e^{\frac 1{2(\phi(u)^2-1)}}$$
and :
$$\tag{3}u(\phi)=D+\frac 1C\;\int e^{-\frac 1{2(\phi^2-1)}}\;d\phi$$

Not sure that this will help you to conclude...

Comment: Well $\;\dfrac{\left(1-\phi(u)^2\right)^2}{(\phi(u)')^2}=-\dfrac {\phi(u)}{\phi''(u)}\;$ shows a nice symmetry...

Comment: This is correct, the problem was wrong (in the sense that it cannot  be solved in the way it says). Thanks.

Comment: @Trollkemada: Glad it helped anyway !

Comment: haven't you tacitly assumed that there exists a bijection between u and $\phi$? @RaymondManzoni

Comment: @aaron: From $(2)$ (and supposing everything smooth at least locally) I observed that $\phi(u)'$ had a constant sign and could be $0$ only for the case $\phi(u)=1$ (the value $\phi=1$ is problematic too in the resulting integral $(3)$ and the lower and upper bounds should be on the same side relatively to $1$). At the end of all these 'formal manipulations' it didn't bother me too much I must admit...